# packaging pygtk application using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I want to create an executable of pygtk application to make it run on any machine without installing the packages.

I tried using pyinstaller. But getting following errors when I run on different machines and text will look like square box in GUI

```
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:88: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home /arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: PangoWarning: No modules found:
No builtin or dynamically loaded modules were found.
PangoFc will not work correctly.
This probably means there was an error in the creation of:
   '/home/arrowdevices/pda/etc/pango/pango.modules'
You should create this file by running:
  pango-querymodules > '/home/arrowdevices/pda/etc/pango/pango.modules'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcd-filter-lcddefault.conf", line 9: invalid constant used : lcddefault
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf", line 17: invalid constant used : lcdlegacy
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: PangoWarning: failed to find shape engine, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: PangoWarning: failed to find shape engine, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='common'
/tmp/_MEIwDbvRA/User.py:197: GtkWarning: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file '/home/arrowdevices/pda/lib/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders.cache': No such file or directory
```

My questions:

1. How can I create a stand alone pygtk application using pyinstaller(step by step instruction)?
2. How can I bundle all the images/fonts which I use in my application together with the application?

Note : I have installed the gtk and pygtk packages(with dependency - glib, atk, cairo, pango, pycairo, pygobject, gdk-pixbuf) by compiling the source to a local directory with python 2.7.

Comment: If you could pack a gtk app with py2exe,pyinstaller and so, let us know! I think the best is to made a local bin dir, with the modules/libs that you need.Valid for images/fonts too. Get a copy of gimp or gramps for win. From gramps, you could keep the root files and put your script on top, instead of gramps. Still, be careful at versions, and don't forget to add regular py modules that you use

Comment: Hey cox, I am able package the stuffs. but when I try it in client machine it gives the above errors. Somehow pyinstaller hard codes the pango.modules path. How to get rid of that. any idea?

Comment: The pixbuf lib is also very important. Wat you are doing is  what I say before, creating a local copy of gtk. Why don't get one allready made? The cache and pango modules are usualy populated on target machine pango-querymodules > %GTKDIR%\etc\pango\pango.modules and gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > %GTKDIR%\lib\gdk-pixbuf-2.0\2.10.0\loaders.cache (with GTKDIR in win path)